# How to connect VS2010 to TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Hi i have to connect VS2010 to TFS 2010, somebody know some tutorial or something like that to follow and configure VS2010 correctly?
Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN has an entire section on [using TFS from Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee854733.aspx) for managing development processes.